# Python 3 Program to print the Initials of a name and with surname

Tags: python-3.x

Program: Input a name and Print the Initials and with surname.

Input:- Ted Vivian Mosby
Output:- T V Mosby

Using Python 3 online compiler:-

https://repl.it/languages/python3

---

```
user = input('Please Enter your name \n')
length = len(user)
value=0

for a in range(0,length-1):
    if a==" ":
      value=a

for b in range(0,value):
    if b==0:
      print(user[0])
    elif user[b]==" ":
      print(user[b+1])

for c in range(value+1,length):
    print(user[c])
```

---

The output I have is:-

Please Enter your name
 Ted Vivian Mosby
e
d

V
i
v
i
a
n

M
o
s
b
y

Comment: for a in range(0,length-1):                                        
    if a==" ":                                                                       
      value=a                                                                              
                                                                                        
This is to Find the starting value of the last Word

Comment: for b in range(0,value):
    if b==0:
      print(user[0])
    elif user[b]==" ":
      print(user[b+1])

--------This is to print the initials before the surname.

Comment: for c in range(value+1,length):
    print(user[c])

----------- To print the surname only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pythonic way to do it. Notice it takes into account all names, no matter how many middle names.

```
name = input("Please enter a name: ")
names = name.split()
initials = [x[0] for x in names[:-1]]
print(*initials, names[-1])


"""
Broken down:
name.split() = ['Ted', 'David', 'Vivican', 'Mosby']   Note ive added an extra name for show
name.split()[:-1] = ['Ted', 'David', 'Vivican']
[x[0] for name in ['Ted', 'David', 'Vivican']] = ['T', 'D', 'V']
print(*initials) unpacks each value in the list to the function eg
print(*['T', 'D', 'V']) == print('T', 'D', 'V')
"""
```

Comment: Getting the following alert:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: It is working now, thank you. If I take a user input instead of statically saving the name, that should also work right ?

Comment: Yes it will, i've edited the top line to show you how to do it.

Comment: Perfect,Thank you.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could accept my answer, kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` to separate out the names. Then print the first char of each name, but the entire last name.

```
user = input('Please Enter your name \n')
names = user.split()

for i in range(0, len(names)):
    if i < len(names) - 1:
        # print first char only, no newline at the end
        print(names[i][0], end=" ") 
    else:
        # print entire last name
        print(names[i]) # print entire name
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this, the program is working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

```
user = input('Please Enter your name \n')
length = len(user.split(" "))
value=0
print(length)
for a in user.split(" "):
   if(value==length-1):
      print(a)
   else:
      print(a[0],end=' ')
   value+=1
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this, Can you help me understand the following line in your program:-

for a in user.split(" "): and print(a[0],end=' ')

Comment: @HanibalBarca for a in user.split(" ") will loop each word in the string user and print(a[0],end='' ') is used to print the initial character of the string if it is not surname of the user name and also end =" " is used so that next output doesn't print in next line.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.